# How to access child 'model' data using parent 'model' to show in grid in extjs

Tags: user-interface, extjs, model, grid, store

Scenario : I have two grid on UI 1st is live-offence 2nd Disposed-offence there is on field in 1st grid 'nextDate' ,model of first grid is 'offence' There is another model which is child of offence model that result model ,and the field next-date is inside result model, and result model is in require of offence model. how to access next-date on grid.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, you can use the [column renderer function](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/classic/Ext.grid.column.Column.html#cfg-renderer), which gives you the row's record as a parameter, and access the child result record from there. I'm not sure how the relationship is setup so you'll have to work that bit out yourself!

```js
renderer: function (value, metaData, record) {
    var resultRecord = record.getResultRecord(); // replace this with correct code!
    
    return resultRecord.get('next-date');
}
```